# How to fix memory increase every time updating tableview data

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I had a javafx application memory keep increasing in over time. This confused me, because I thought I had a memory leak in my code.
i found memory increase every time updating tableview data,there isn't any new objects just updating old data.

The intent of the following code is to reproduce the same problem

```
public class TableViewSample extends Application {

    private boolean running = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");

        TableView<Foo> table = new TableView<>();
        ObservableList<Foo> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new Foo(0, 0, 0, 0), new Foo(0, 0, 0, 0), new Foo(0, 0, 0, 0),
                new Foo(0, 0, 0, 0), new Foo(0, 0, 0, 0), new Foo(0, 0, 0, 0),
                new Foo(0, 0, 0, 0), new Foo(0, 0, 0, 0), new Foo(0, 0, 0, 0),
                new Foo(0, 0, 0, 0), new Foo(0, 0, 0, 0), new Foo(0, 0, 0, 0),
                new Foo(0, 0, 0, 0), new Foo(0, 0, 0, 0), new Foo(0, 0, 0, 0),
                new Foo(0, 0, 0, 0), new Foo(0, 0, 0, 0), new Foo(0, 0, 0, 0),
                new Foo(0, 0, 0, 0), new Foo(0, 0, 0, 0), new Foo(0, 0, 0, 0),
                new Foo(0, 0, 0, 0), new Foo(0, 0, 0, 0), new Foo(0, 0, 0, 0),
                new Foo(0, 0, 0, 0), new Foo(0, 0, 0, 0), new Foo(0, 0, 0, 0)
        );
        Random random = new Random();

        TableColumn<Foo, Integer> num1Col = new TableColumn<>("num1");
        num1Col.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("num1"));
        TableColumn<Foo, Integer> num2Col = new TableColumn<>("num2");
        num2Col.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("num2"));
        TableColumn<Foo, Integer> num3Col = new TableColumn<>("num3");
        num3Col.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("num3"));
        TableColumn<Foo, Integer> num4Col = new TableColumn<>("num4");
        num4Col.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("num4"));

        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(num1Col, num2Col, num3Col, num4Col);

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), event -> {
            for (Foo foo : data) {
                foo.setNum1(random.nextInt(1000));
                foo.setNum2(random.nextInt(1000));
                foo.setNum3(random.nextInt(1000));
                foo.setNum4(random.nextInt(1000));
            }
        }));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);

        Button btn = new Button("start");
        btn.setOnAction(event -> {
            if (running) {
                timeline.stop();
                running = false;
                btn.setText("start");
            } else {
                timeline.play();
                running = true;
                btn.setText("stop");
            }
            event.consume();
        });

        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(btn, table);
        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(vbox);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static class Foo {
        private SimpleIntegerProperty num1;
        private SimpleIntegerProperty num2;
        private SimpleIntegerProperty num3;
        private SimpleIntegerProperty num4;


        public Foo(int num1, int num2, int num3, int num4) {
            this.num1 = new SimpleIntegerProperty(num1);
            this.num2 = new SimpleIntegerProperty(num2);
            this.num3 = new SimpleIntegerProperty(num3);
            this.num4 = new SimpleIntegerProperty(num4);
        }

        public int getNum1() {
            return num1.get();
        }

        public SimpleIntegerProperty num1Property() {
            return num1;
        }

        public void setNum1(int num1) {
            this.num1.set(num1);
        }

        public int getNum2() {
            return num2.get();
        }

        public SimpleIntegerProperty num2Property() {
            return num2;
        }

        public void setNum2(int num2) {
            this.num2.set(num2);
        }

        public int getNum3() {
            return num3.get();
        }

        public SimpleIntegerProperty num3Property() {
            return num3;
        }

        public void setNum3(int num3) {
            this.num3.set(num3);
        }

        public int getNum4() {
            return num4.get();
        }

        public SimpleIntegerProperty num4Property() {
            return num4;
        }

        public void setNum4(int num4) {
            this.num4.set(num4);
        }
    }
}
```

Am i doing something wrong and how to fix this memory increase?

Comment: Have you run your code through a debugger to see when/where the memory increases begin?

Comment: Did you get an OutOfMemoryError?

Comment: I guess since the program seems to create many objects every second (the table classes likely will create Integer wrapper objects for the primitive int values), they will just fill the memory until they get removed by the GC...

Comment: I tried running the gc and nothing get removed, memory keep increase and never go down, if i stop updating the data the memory stop increasing but the increased memory never get removed

Comment: Did you check to make sure the GC actually ran? Requesting a GC run does not guarantee it will happen.

Comment: Also, what version are you using? I don't observe the perpetual memory increase using OpenJFX 11.0.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: Everything seems to be fine when I ran the program. `Java: 1.8.0_144` on `Windows 10`.

Comment: running on `java: 1.8.0_191` on `Ubuntu 16.04 amd64 Linux 4.15.0-43-generic`. it's increasing in over time after 30 min gets up to 500mb in Task manager but in `jconsole` the heap and non heap memory seems ok with 12mb and 35mb while in my task manager it take over 600mb. if i leave the app running the system run out of memory and just freezes, i don't get any error before the pc freeze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tasted same code on windows with same jdk version and everything fine.
I have build executable jar on ubuntu twice using different jdk versions and tested it on both windows and ubuntu and result in the same issue on both platforms. so ubuntu jdk produce the same issue no matter what jdk version is used, i will continue coding on windows for now and will try a fresh ubuntu installation later. thanks for helping

edit:
after some search found some related bug reports [JDK-8161997](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8161997), [JDK-8161911](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8161911) seems the problem related to JavaFX is using hardware pipeline.
after a fresh ubuntu 18.04 installation everything works fine.